# What are the characters that appear under a value entered into the Chrome console?

Tags: google-chrome, console

When I paste a value into the Chrome console, Chrome adds a line below with a negative number.

[image]

At first I thought it related to the value, which exists in the document. However, as I back out each character the value underneath changes and then disappears. If I replace the later characters the value changes incrementally.

[image]

There's no tooltip or context menu on the line.

What the heck is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the result of your calculation, Chrome thinks you're calculating..

001 minus 984 minus 52

Comment: Heh. I was just about to delete after realizing that this was the case. I see now that it evaluates a range of statements in a similar manner even before hitting enter. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It's called [Eager Evaluation](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/05/devtools#eagerevaluation), new in Chrome 68.

[image: Screenshot of the feature in action as documented by Chrome's team]